# Can't find and open pdf with PyPDF2

Tags: pdf, pypdf, pyttsx3

I can't get my code to find my PDF file. It is in the same folder as my project and i see it in my files in Pycharm. I also tried similar codes, same error here for the same command. Any advices on how to make it connect with my files?

Error message: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'plan.pdf'

```
    import pyttsx3
    import PyPDF2
    book = open("thinkpython.pdf", "rb")
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(book)
    pages = pdf_reader.numPages
    print(pages)
    speaker = pyttsx3.init()
    page = pdf_reader.getPage(55)
    text = page.extractText()
    speaker.say(text)
    speaker.runAndWait()
```

I tried using the whole "link" but it did not work. I also tried to find help on youtube.

Comment: You have identified what the file's name is, but not *where* that file is located.

Comment: pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open("C:\Users\louis\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\håndbok.pdf", "rb"))  i also tried with the direct files like this. I'm a total newbie..

Answer (score 0):

As PyPDF2 was deprecated in 2022 I use the replacement pypdf instead. It was updated as late as today.

os.path is used to get the file path and to join the path to the file name. Trying just to add strings together won't work very well as you might have seen.

```
import pyttsx3
import pypdf
import os.path

book_name = "thinkpython.pdf"
book_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), book_name)

book = open(book_path, "rb")
pdf_reader = pypdf.PdfReader(book)
pages = pdf_reader.pages
print(pages)

speaker = pyttsx3.init()
page = pdf_reader.pages[55]
text = page.extract_text()
speaker.say(text)
speaker.runAndWait()
```

You can find the docs for pypdf here:  https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/PdfReader.html